# Pagination repeats posts several times on first page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, pagination

I'm having an issue with pagination on my site. I created an event list and for past events, I added the same pagination code that's in the category.php file. This is unfortunately outputting the list of past events several times on each page (like the same events listed 6 times on page 1, then the remaining events listed on the second page 6 times). What's wrong with my code?

Here you can see the problem: http://www.mybeatfix-new.com

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts('paged='.$paged.'&cat='.$cat); ?>        


<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>                     
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 
$eventquery = array (
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'orderby' => '_cmb_event-date',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'meta_value' => time(),
    'meta_key' => '_cmb_event-date',
    'meta_compare' => '<',
    'paged' => $paged,
    );
?>

<?php $myeventlist = new WP_Query($eventquery); ?>
<?php while ($myeventlist->have_posts()) : $myeventlist->the_post(); 
        $data_event     = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_event-date', true);
        $pretty_date = date('D M j Y', $data_event);
        $m_day = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_day', true );
        $m_start_time = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_start_time', true );
        $m_end_time = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_end_time', true );
        $m_venue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_venue', true );
        $event_text     = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_cmb_e_details", true);
        $event_price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_price', true );
        $event_ticket_status = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_ticket_status', true );
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'event-image');

?>
<div class="elist-single">

<div class="elist-thumb">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo $thumbnail; ?></a></div>

<div class="elist-right">
<div class="elist-title">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo ShortenText(get_the_title()); ?></a>
</div>


<div class="elist-date"><?php echo $pretty_date; ?> </div><br  />
<div class="elist-info">
<i class="icon-home"> <?php echo $m_venue; ?> </i><br  />
<i class="icon-time"> <?php echo $m_start_time; ?> - <?php echo $m_end_time; ?></i><br  />
<?php echo $event_price ?><br  />
</div><br  />


</div>
</div>


<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endwhile; endif;?>


<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
<?php get_template_part ('inc/pagination');?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have created a loop within a loop. You are saying while you have posts loop through all the posts so it is doing so 6 times presumably because you have 6 posts.

If you use two loops you need to `<?php endwhile;?>` after the first loop and to `wp_reset_postdata();` after `WP_Query()` but you should be able do it in one. `WP_Query` should give you all the information you need on its own complete with pagination.

For reference : [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mantis! Sorry for being such a newb. lol Anyway I added the Paged query within the wp_query... The actual pagination is working and I can tell because if I head to http://www.mybeatfix-new.com/past-events/page/2/ the remaining events are there, but the buttons aren't coming up.

Comment: `<?php $myeventlist = new WP_Query($eventquery); ?>
<?php while ($myeventlist->have_posts()) : $myeventlist->the_post(); 
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; `

Comment: It's better to update code by editing the original question rather than putting it in the comments. You shouldn't need a separate pagination query. Just add `'posts_per_page=3'`for example, as an argument to `WP_Query` There are examples of this on the codex page.